# Как убрать смещение страницы при появлении скроллинга

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код:

```
// эта функция двигает body, чтобы оно не прыгало если на сайте появилась прокрутка
function ret() { 
    bodyH = getDocumentHeight(); //проверяем высоту документа
    clientH = getClientHeight(); //проверяем высоту окна браузера
    razn = (bodyH - clientH);
    if (razn>0)  $("body").css("margin", "0 0 0 0");
    else $("body").css("margin", "0 0 0 -17px");
}
ret();
```

Все работает кроме `background: url(img/bg.jpg) 100% 100% fixed no-repeat;` фон смещается при появлении скроллера.

Comment: background к какому элементу привязан?

Comment: А вы знаете, что в разных браузерах прокрутка разной ширины, не говоря уже о мобильных браузерах?

Comment: @CoddWrench body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял вам нужно сделать следующее:

Добавить отдельный тег для фона:

```
<div id="bg"> </div>
```

Для него стиль:

```
#bg {
    background: url(img/bg.jpg) 100% 100% fixed no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Весь контент который будет прокручиваться нужно поместить внутрь тега:

```
<div id="content"> </div>
```

И для него прописать вот такой стиль:

```
#content {
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;  
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Выглядит это вот так:

[image: Тест прокрутки]

Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/n7ezvuan/).